# How do I get images in Javascript array centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, center

I am so stumped at this point and its bugging me to no end that I can not figure it out so I have decided to switch the way I enter images on my github site its a small meme site dedicated to cats and it is a gallery site and I can not get these images to center to the center of the page horizontally my code is below

```js
var images = ['ghc1', 'ghc2', 'ghc3', 'ghc4', 'ghc5', 'ghc6', 'ghc7',
  'ghc8', 'ghc9', 'ghc10', 'ghc11', 'ghc12', 'ghc13', 'ghc14', 'ghc15',
  'ghc16'
];
var container = document.querySelector('#images');
images.forEach(function(file) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'images/ghc/' + file + '.jpg';
  container.appendChild(img);
});
```

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

body {
  background-color: #87CEEB;
}

#images>img {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  max-width: 25vw;
  -ms-flex: 25%;
  /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#images {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Girls + Cats</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img alt="Girls + Cats" src="images/girlsholdingcats.png">
  </div>
  <div id="images" class=images>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <a href="index.html"><img alt="Home Page" src="images/homepage.png"></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `display: flex;` property needs to be applied to the container.

I've just changed `#images` CSS to:

```
#images {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

And removed `display: flex` from images.

---

Your code modified:

```js
var images = ['ghc1', 'ghc2', 'ghc3', 'ghc4', 'ghc5', 'ghc6', 'ghc7',
  'ghc8', 'ghc9', 'ghc10', 'ghc11', 'ghc12', 'ghc13', 'ghc14', 'ghc15',
  'ghc16'
];
var container = document.querySelector('#images');
images.forEach(function(file) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'images/ghc/' + file + '.jpg';
  container.appendChild(img);
});
```

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

body {
  background-color: #87CEEB;
}

#images > img {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}

#images {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Girls + Cats</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img alt="Girls + Cats" src="images/girlsholdingcats.png">
  </div>
  <div id="images" class=images>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <a href="index.html"><img alt="Home Page" src="images/homepage.png"></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This causes images to lose original sizes and distorts them but it does however center them any ideas on how to fix the distortion ideas? I know i forgot to mention not all my images are the same size

Comment: You will need to implement some responsive behavior in your images.
Check how [bulma.io](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/image/) do this in [this file](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/css/bulma.css#L4314) (check rules `.image {...}` and `.image img {...}`)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the js code and css code

```js
var images = ['ghc1', 'ghc2', 'ghc3', 'ghc4', 'ghc5', 'ghc6', 'ghc7',
  'ghc8', 'ghc9', 'ghc10', 'ghc11', 'ghc12', 'ghc13', 'ghc14', 'ghc15',
  'ghc16'
];
var container = document.querySelector('#images');
images.forEach(function(file) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'images/ghc/' + file + '.jpg';
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'flex'
  div.appendChild(img)
  container.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

body {
  background-color: #87CEEB;
}

.flex>img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  max-width: 100%;
}
.flex{
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
}
#images {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Girls + Cats</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img alt="Girls + Cats" src="images/girlsholdingcats.png">
  </div>
  <div id="images" class=images>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <a href="index.html"><img alt="Home Page" src="images/homepage.png"></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This does not work I am trying to make a responsive grid with what i have this just causes all images to just be 1 per line